# navigator.vibrate more than 1 time

Tags: javascript

how do I do the navigator.vibrate method more than 1 time ? this only do one vibrate :

```
navigator.vibrate(500);
navigator.vibrate(500);
navigator.vibrate(500);
```

I also tried with sleep but still doesn't work :/

Comment: JavaScript is **not** Java. I'm going to go ahead and assume, based on the posted answer, that this question is about JavaScript and has nothing to do with Java, and remove the Java tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have 1 vibration process going at 1 time. Any previous vibrate process is halted and the next one is started.

If you were meaning to have the vibration go on and then off then start again you need to pass vibrate() an array of values, alternating between the length of the vibration and length of pause.

So if you wanted it to vibrate 3 different times for 500 milliseconds with say 300 millisecond pauses in between then you would do so like:

```
navigator.vibrate([500,300,500,300,500);
```

Make sure to read [vibrate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate) reference, and the [Vibration API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API) docs